# Data-Migration ElasticSearch 5.6.16 to 7.2.0

Tags: database, elasticsearch, migration, database-migration

how can i perfom full data migration from ElasticSearch 5.6.16 to 7.2.0. I have an application running version 5.6.16. No i have to update some of the data to version 7.2.0. The manufacturer has written / provided an own tool for the migration, but this requires that the new installation (7.2.0) has been installed on a new separate server. But this is the only the last option for me. So what's an easy and good way to do this on the same machine? Or would it be an solution to install the new version (7.2.0) on the same machine with different port and then do my stuff as this would be two servers?

First backup the data and the re-import after installing new version? Did i get problems with the indexes (i read something about this.. that this could result in errors)

Answer (score 1):

You have few questions but I  will try to answer two important ones,

1. How can you run the two different version of elasticsearch on a single machine

Answer : **it is possible although not recommended in production environment**, as you guess it right, by running these two version on different ports.

2. How to migrate from ES 5.6 to 7.2

Answer: Elasticsearch provides the backward compatibility till last major version, so if you are upgrading to 7.X, than ES 6.X indices can be backed up and re-imported in ES 7.X but you can't do this for 5.X indices.

Note: Refer [upgrade elasticsearch official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) for detailed explanation and process.

Comment: to point 1: yes, after data migration with the provided tools/scripts i want to delete the old instance, so this should not make any problem, especially in production environment or will it? to point 2: the manufactor has proved some curl command for re-indexing, which should "fix" this problem. So in my eyes the best way is to install new version on different port and drive-location, then run the migration stuff from the manufactor and delete the old installed version or?

Comment: @Opa114 sorry for delay in response, reg 1.) unless you are querying both the ES instances same time, it shouldn't cause issue, and reg 2) if you have a way(tool/script) which works(hope you test it before trying it on production data ) then your approach sounds good to me.